# CakePHP - Just find related model data

Tags: cakephp

I have Users and Dashboards.  They both have a HABTM relationship with each other.  How do I just retrieve all of a user's dashboards, without any of the User data?

I tried this but it returns the User model as well:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->User->find('all', array('contain' => 'Dashboard'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `fields` option so that you retrieve only the id field and none of the others. (You probably can't set it to fetch no fields at all.)

```
$this->User->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'contain' => 'Dashboard',
        'fields'  => 'User.id'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dashboard model instead with a condition for the user id:

```
$this->User->Dashboard->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('DashboardsUsers')));
$this->User->Dashboard->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
      'recursive' => -1
));
```

I think that should work :)

Comment: It doesn't work because the dashboards table doesn't have a `user_id` column.  They have a join table called `dashboards_users` that has `id, dashboard_id, user_id`

Comment: It should work if you have set up your associations correctly... http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Comment: Just realized that I was missing the bindModel() method. Let me know if this works please

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Same error, but you have some syntax errors btw.

Comment: yeap, was missing a closing bracket